# setInterval() behaves differently in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, browser, setinterval

I wrote a function and wanted it to display 1 to 10 after every second in a span. While debugging the program I  wanted to log the results  to a console and saw different results for firefox and chrome, Chrome also changes the results ater every page refresh.

Below is my function:

```
function log10()  {
        for(var i =0;i<=10;i++)
        {
            console.log(setInterval(function() {
                $("span").text(i)
            },6000));
        }
}
```

FIREFOX RESULT LOGS: 2 to 11 (via firebug) and remains same on reload.

CHROME SHOWS:  1 to 11 (via built in debugger) And after every reload it shows 22 to 22 / 23 to 33 / 34 to 34 et-al

I am calling function via `<body onload = log10();>`

Does anyone know whats happening. I am more Interesting in knowing how to log 1 to 10 in span as per my code `$("span").text(i)`

Comment: The `return` from `setInterval` returns `a JavaScript Object containing all informations needed by an animation (like the this object, the callback function, the length, the frame-rate).`. Src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

Answer (score 3):

You are not saving context, using an anonymous function for saving context. You should use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, as `setInterval` will not stop until you stop it (using `clearInterval` or by unloading the page). At the other hand `setTimeout` will run only once for each loop with delay of 6000ms. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uyzes/)

```
function log10()  {
    var i = 0;
    function repeat(){
        if(i > 10 ) return;
        setTimeout(repeat, 600);
        $("span").text(i);
        i++;
    } 
    repeat();
}
```

Comment: This is an IIFE, immediately-invoked-function-expression.

Comment: And why are the results different in FF and Chrome

Comment: @Mike - `console.log()` behaves very differently in FF and Chrome.

Comment: @Mike There was a problem with previous code. I changed it based on your requirement.  Noe it should solve your problem.

Comment: @Jasper: Do you have a link to IIFE

Comment: @Mike Here is the first article I read about it: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: @Mike sorry I forgot to call repeat for first time now it is working see http://jsfiddle.net/Uyzes/

Comment: @Sushil - Nice, but if we're going over IIFEs, then why pollute the global namespace by calling log10 from it... just make it an IIFE ==> http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/B8rt7/

Comment: @PeterAjtai log10 needed as he want it to run on wondow.onload.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/8sdu5/2/

```
function log10()  {
    var counter = 1;
    var evt = setInterval(function() {
        $("span").text(counter++);
        if(counter > 10)
            clearInterval(evt);
    }, 1000);
}
```

You don't need a loop, the setInterval will "loop" on its own, you just have to have a condition to tell it when to stop.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into variable binding issues. A different way to solve them is to pass in the number to be shown combined with recursion and setTimeout:

#### [Working jsFidle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/zkDCC/)

```
// recursive function
function log10(theNumber)  {
        if (theNumber <= 10)
        {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("span").text(theNumber);
                log10(++theNumber);
            },1000);
        }
}

// kick things off
log10(0);
```

Comment: @Mike - Because of `log10(theNumber)`. The first time you call it, you have to call log10 with a defined value. In the linked jsFiddle you call it with "theNumber" which is undefined at that point.... try log10(0) like in my example above ==> http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/zkDCC/11/